# animation-iteration-count не работает

Tags: css

```
animation-iteration-count: 2, 2, 3;
```

Не понимаю почему animation-iteration-count работает только для последней анимации?

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: boxMove 4s 0s linear, boxMove2 2s 4s linear, boxMove3 4s linear 6s forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 2, 2, 3; /*Сработает только boxMove3(произойдет 3 итерации), а остальные нет*/
}

@keyframes boxMove {
  from {
    transform: translate(0px) rotate(0deg);
        }
  to {
    transform: translate(400px) rotate(144deg);
  }
}

@keyframes boxMove2 {
  from {
    transform: translate(400px) rotate(144deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(400px, 72px) rotate(216deg);
  }
}

@keyframes boxMove3 {
  from {
    transform: translate(400px, 72px) rotate(216deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(700px, 100px) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У моей машины четыре колеса, почему вращается только четвертое?

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex, если есть 3 keyframes и соответственно animation-iteration-count: 2, 2, 3;, то почему срабатывает только для последнего keyframes?

Comment: Выложи уже код, тебе никто не ответит пока ты не предоставишь достаточно информации

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex дополнил

Comment: Так не получится сделать. Нужно все эти три анимации объединить в одну. Первые две анимации ведь не могут ждать после своего выполнения пока закончится третья и на последующих итерациях у всех этих анимаций уже нету дилэя... получается каша какая-то.

Comment: это можно сделать с помощью Js, если нужно именно 3 отдельные анимации

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex да, действительно каша. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  
}

#ok {
  background-color: green;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes bgchange {
  from {
    background: green;
  }
  to {
    background: red;
  }
}

@keyframes swing {
  15% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-5px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(3px);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateX(-3px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(2px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.swing:hover {
  animation-name: blink, bgchange, swing;
  animation-duration: 1s, 1s, 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2, 2, 3;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="swing">У моей машины четыре колеса, почему вращается только четвертое?</div>
<div class="swing">У моей машины четыре колеса, почему вращается только четвертое?</div>
<div class="swing">У моей машины четыре колеса, почему вращается только четвертое?</div>
<div class="swing" id="ok">Не понимаю почему animation-iteration-count работает только для последней анимации?</div>
```

Comment: хороший ответ. Поздравляю со второй тысячей!

Comment: 3.5 было бы репы :))))  полторы отдано, впечатляет